# How to write dynamically typed data to field within a struct

Tags: go, interface

I have the following response struct that I want to use as a base wrapper for responding to API calls users send to me.

```
type Response struct {
  Data      ???                     `json:"data,omitempty"`
  Time      int64                   `json:"time,omitempty"`
  Message   string                  `json:"message,omitempty"`
}
```

The type of the Data field is varying and could be a `map[string]*CustomStruct1` `map[string*CustomStruct2` or an `[]CustomStruct3`.

What is the best way to attack this kind of problem?

Comment: You're probably looking for the empty interface `interface{}` it works for any type because every type satisfies the requirement of having at least zero methods. Looking at your struct, you might want to get your `Time` and `Message` fields through [embedding](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding) instead and use a separate struct for each response type.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to simply treat "Data" as the `interface{}` (any) type, instead of using your custom structs, and handle the resulting values based on inspection of what actually got unmarshaled. Of course, once you've inspected the data to determine what type it should be you could convert it into the appropriate strong type after the fact.

```
type Response struct {
  Data      interface{} `json:"data,omitempty"`
  Time      int64       `json:"time,omitempty"`
  Message   string      `json:"message,omitempty"`
}
```

Another option is to embed the "Response" struct into specialized structs that look for your custom types and unmarshal into the appropriate one, assuming you know which one you've got ahead of time:

```
type BaseResponse struct {
  Time      int64  `json:"time,omitempty"`
  Message   string `json:"message,omitempty"`
}

type Response1 struct {
  BaseResponse
  Data map[string]*CustomStruct1 `json:"data"`
}

type Response2 struct {
  BaseResponse
  Data map[string]*CustomStruct2 `json:"data"`
}

// etc...
```

Ultimately, the unmarshaler cannot *pick* a varying type based on the document that gets unmarshaled, it only deserializes JSON values into structures either defined explicitly by you or into generic ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use reflection, but it wouldn't be very idiomatic.